# How to find start and end points of filltext in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Hey there how am i going to find the start and end point of a canvas

i have created a letter like this on a canvas

```
var centerx = (c.width - cx.measureText(letter).width) / 2;
        var centery = c.height / 2;
        console.log("Bilawal");
        console.log(cx.measureText(letter));
        var lines = letter.split('\n');
        var lineheight = 20;
        //for (var i = 0; i<lines.length; i++)
        //cx.fillText(lines[i], centerx, centery + (i*lineheight) );

        console.log("X "+centerx+" Y "+centery);
        cx.fillText(letter, centerx, centery);
```

now i dont know how to find the start X,Y and end X,Y

Comment: Just a guess...
startx would be centerx, starty would be centery - (cx.measureText(letter).height /2). endx would be (c.width / 2) +  (cx.measureText(letter).width /2) and endy would be centery + (cx.measureText(letter).height /2)

Comment: @AnyMoose how would i implement this in code i am weak in maths :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked for a code sample. Below I have included the same math. Hope this helps.

```js
var centerx = (c.width - cx.measureText(letter).width) / 2;
        var centery = c.height / 2;
        console.log("Bilawal");
        console.log(cx.measureText(letter));
        var lines = letter.split('\n');
        var lineheight = 20;
        //for (var i = 0; i<lines.length; i++)
        //cx.fillText(lines[i], centerx, centery + (i*lineheight) );

        console.log("X "+centerx+" Y "+centery);
        cx.fillText(letter, centerx, centery);

        startx = centerx;
        starty = centery - 10;
        endx = (c.width / 2) + (cx.measureText(letter).width / 2); 
        endy = centery + 10;
```

Start and end for each letter as you asked. Once it runs you can access the array of COORDS "startsEnds". If the space between the letters is to large drop the spacer value.

```js
function COORD(sx,sy,ex,ey) {
    this.startX = sx;
    this.startY = sy;
    this.endX = ex;
    this.endY = ey;
}

var startsEnds = [];
var spacer = 1;
var centerx = (c.width - cx.measureText(letter).width) / 2;
        var centery = c.height / 2;
        console.log("Bilawal");
        console.log(cx.measureText(letter));
        console.log("X "+centerx+" Y "+centery);

        var lines = letter.split('\n');
        var lineheight = 20;
        //for (var i = 0; i<lines.length; i++)
        //cx.fillText(lines[i], centerx, centery + (i*lineheight) );
        var lett = letter.split("");

        var newCenterX = centerx;
        var newCenterY = centery;

        for (var i = 0; i < lett.length; i++){

            console.log("X "+newCenterX+" Y "+newCenterY );


            var startEnd = new COORD(newCenterX,newCenterY - 10,(c.width / 2) + (cx.measureText(lett[i]).width / 2), newCenterY + 10);
            startsEnds.push(startEnd);

            newCenterX = newCenterX + cx.measureText(lett[i]) + spacer;

        }
        cx.fillText(letter, centerx, centery);
```

Comment: End Y gives NaN

Comment: Start X 151.2939453125Start Y 150
End X 548.7060546875 End Y NaN

Comment: value of Centry 150

Comment: Oh my bad, MeasureText is only width. I edited my answer and used half of your line height, please try the new code.

Comment: Thanks man it did the job just what i wanted. I last thing if possible for u if not then i will accept ur answer write away

Comment: Like i have 3 letters C A R is is it possible that i can get the X and Y of each of the letters

Comment: the letter is text not array like var letter = "CAR"

Comment: it seems that it show only one letter on the canvas

Comment: can u get x and y of each letters